# How to hide particular column in dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: html, dojo

i have grid with some columns... i want to hide one column in that grid... how to do that...

here is my grid.... in this i need to hide CWDocId header from grid...

```
<div class="claro" id="CWPWORKLIST__2" name="dataGrid" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','inner__CWPWORKLIST__2')" ondblclick="editDataGridResponseMapping(this.id)" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="height:250px; left:auto; position:absolute; top:333px; width:920px;">
     <table class="claro" dojotype="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="inner__CWPWORKLIST__2" rowselector="10px">
          <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th field="CWDocId" width="100px" style="display:none;">
                         CWDocId
                    </th>
                    <th field="Due" width="100px">
                         Due
                    </th>
                    <th field="Participant" width="100px">
                         Participant
                    </th>
                    <th field="User" width="100px">
                         User
                    </th>
                    <th field="Task" width="100px">
                         Task
                    </th>
                    <th field="Details" width="100px">
                         Details
                    </th>
                    <th field="Created" width="100px">
                         Created
                    </th>
                    <th field="Assigned" width="100px">
                         Assigned
                    </th>
                    <th field="Started" width="100px">
                         Started
                    </th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
     </table>
     <input id="hidden__CWPWORKLIST__2" name="orcl1.cw" style="display:none;" type="hidden" value="CWDocId##CWDOCID,Due##DUE_DATE,Participant##PARTICIPANT_TYPE,User##USER_ID,Task##OPERATION,Details##ORDER_VK,Created##CREATION_DATE,Assigned##ASSIGN_TO_USER_DATE,Started##START_WORK_DATE">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought of giving a column an ID and by using dojo.style method or CSS to set its visibility?